# some CSS value replacement with regex

Tags: css, regex

I have some CSS property replacement issue. I want to find and replace all values for font-family . for example :

Replace:

```
 font-family : Tahoma;
```

AND

```
font-family:Arial , sans-serif
```

With:

```
font-family : Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
```

have you any idea how I can do this with regex ?

Comment: You don't need a regex for that.

Comment: @Dai I want to use the pattern in my idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern to get font-family and all value of that , then you can replace it with anything you want:

```
font\-family(\s|):(.*?)(;|">)
```

you can test this pattern in regexr.com:
https://regexr.com/5j8t2